# Como mudar a mensagem de boas vindas ao logar!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp

eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em ASP.NET MVC, por padrão ele já vem com um template pré-definido, no entanto ao fazer login na aplicação é exibido a mensagem "Olá email@emaildologado.com !", mas eu queria que ao invés de aparecer o email fosse exibido o nome da pessoa logado, pois eu criei esse campo no banco de dados, para armazenar o nome na tela de Registrar. Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Abaixo o trecho responsável por exibir a mensagem na tela:

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Olá " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Sair</a></li>
    </ul>
    }
```

Comment: Sim, alguém poderia ajudar. Qual é o trecho de código que coloca a mensagem em tela?

Comment: @Renan eu não achei que fosse necessário incluir o trecho, pois ele é padrão em todos os projetos asp net mvc quando criamos!

Comment: É comum customizar esse código... De qualquer forma, acho que agora há informação suficiente.

Comment: @Renan como seria essa customização, você tem alguma ideia? O mais %&*@ é que já fiz isso, portanto tem muito tempo e eu não tenho mais o projeto para dar uma olhada!

Comment: Eu também estou enferrujado. Espero que você obtenha uma boa resposta. Se não conseguir uma até amanhã, eu posso colocar uma recompensa nesta pergunta. De qualquer forma... O ideal seria você carregar um objeto que represente o usuário através do framework MVC do ASP.NET. Coloque esse objeto na página e todos os campos dele estarão disponíveis no frontend.

Comment: Você deseja o nome completo ou o UserName?

Comment: Pode ser o nome completo, não tem problema, quero apenas que não seja o email, pois o login aqui nesse caso não é feito com username apenas com o email mesmo, foi a requisição aqui da empresa, se o login fosse feito dessa forma seria mais fácil!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para recuperar a propriedade `Name` do usuário logado, basta chamar `User.Identity.Name`

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Olá " + User.Identity.Name + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Sair</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

Quando se chama o `User.Identity` você terá acesso a todas propriedades do usuário logado.

Comment: Não é isso meu amigo, continua a exibir o email, eu acho que eu terei que alterar essa seguinte linha no Register do meu `accountController:  var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };`

Comment: eu ia te perguntar justamente isso, se vc não estava salvando o e-mail no name, onde vc salva o nome do usuário?

Comment: é isso mesmo o UserName terá que receber model.NomeCompleto e model.Email.... problema resolvido... obrigado a todos que ajudaram!